# Limit sql in Cakephp find function

Tags: cakephp

How can I use limit in sql in cakephp...I mean follwoing is the sql...

```
select * from emp limit 3,4
```

How can use above limit [3,4] in find function ...

Answer (score 22):

Better way: `$this->Emp->find('all', array('limit'=>4, 'offset'=>3);`

Comment: and don't forget to require the model like this:  
`$uses=array('Emp')` in the controller.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested it, but it should be something like this in the controller:

```
$this->Emp->find('all',array('limit'=>'3,4'));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Something like this was used in a datatable paginating component I have, where `limit` specified both the offset and the limit as a string rather than only the limit as an int. After updating to CakePHP 2.7.3, it broke. Changing it to using the proper options worked. If you check the CakePHP source code, if you somehow had `limit` defined as this answer suggests and also have the `offset` option set, it's going to generate an extra number and result in invalid SQL syntax. Use your APIs as designed.